# wget: Download Files with Specific Names

Tags: bash, download, wget

I try to download file from a website which is updated every day.
I managed to download all the gz files with the command:

```
wget -r  --no-parent -A.gz --no-directories -R robots http://www.web.com/some_path/
```

But now I want to download only the files with specific name, **e.g** **"FullList"**. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`-A` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html) followed by your string, as in `-A "string*"`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-O` option for `wget`. Example:

```
wget https://sample.com/movie/gameofthrones.mp4 -O Session01Part03.mp4
```